# Prevent wildcard expansion on find

Tags: shell, find, wildcards

Is there a way to prevent wildcard expansion on the `find` command so that the following would work?

```
find . -iname "foo [bar]"
```

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion), I tried running `set -f`, `set -o noglob` and `setopt noglob` just before `find` but it didn't work.

It's a `bash` script and I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

I know I could just escape the wildcard characters but I fear I might leave one out.

Comment: What do you means by “would work”? The command you posted does work. If it doesn't do what you want, tell us what you want it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @njsg already said, the problem is caused by `find`, not the shell: The double quotes you are using are already protecting your expression from the shell; it is passed to `find` unmodified.

The problem is that `find` treats the argument to `-name` and `-iname` as a pattern. The only way to suppress that would be to use a `find` option that does not treat its argument as a pattern. But `find` has no such thing, according to my manual page, so what you want cannot be done. The best you can do is enhance your script to escape the brackets automatically, before passing them to `find`. The following funny-looking `sed` substitution will do that for you:

```
echo "foo [bar]" | sed 's/[][]/\\&/g'
```

Will print: `foo \[bar\]`

Comment: Thanks, alexis. I'll accept your answer for being the most complete and pushing me to a good path to do all the escaping I have to do.

Comment: Good answer.   Certainly GNU find has no such option (and I don't recall anybody ever asking for it).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not with the shell, but with find. The argument to `-name` and `-iname` is a *pattern* itself. `[bar]` will mean `b`, `a` or `r` to `find`. Try just escaping the square brackets, that is:

```
find . -iname 'foo \[bar\]'
```

(Edit: With this, you are not escaping them at the shell level, but passing the backslashes to `find`.)

Comment: Thanks, njsg. I'm looking for a solution that does not depends on escaping the wildcards.

Comment: Ah, right, I missed that, sorry. As @alexis said, this largely depends on whether `find` supports it. And, from what @alexis said, it does not seem to. I'd indeed suggest alexis' sed idea.